# How do I partially delete an object's outer glow in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: shadow, adobe-illustrator

How would I go about making it look like these rings are interlocking, with a shadow (outer glow) effect?

This is where I'm at:
[image]

And this is roughly what I'm after:
[image]

I've been trying for a while now and can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with two circles, instead you can make that shape using **4** half circles.
If you dont know how to break a circle into 2 half ones, [you can watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oneEhq82a6I).
unfortunately after a lot of work what you get is not as good as it should be:
[image]
[image]
What I personally prefer to do here is to cut the path (full circle) on a little far from the place the glow wants to be and in both sides (using scissors tool - which is in the eraser tool's box).
[image]
red is for the right circle and blue is for the left.
Now what is left is that you should apply glow only to the cutted parts. after some moving up and down of layers, you see another problem. I solved it with a 1/4 circle. the result is here:
[image]
and the layers are like this (remember, each part in a layer)
[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for taking the time for those screenshots!

Comment: @OskarH you are welcome! you may now accept and close the question.